# How come nobody answers my questions?

Tags: discussion

I have asked numerous questions on this forum and almost none have been. I’ve never been this ignored on any other forum ever?! What do I have to get attention, and answers.

Comment: for example you ask in one of your questions if you can add an IK to an armature, but your question is much too vague, yes you can add an IK to any armature, but in that precise case, where are you trying to add an IK, what to do, etc... plus it looks like it's an imported armature, not sure it's very controllable...

Comment: maybe not enough people to answer ? / or the question is not clear ? / or too complicated ? you have another big blender website where you can ask your questions: https://blenderartists.org/c/support/9/l/new

Comment: Most of your question is not well structured to make people understand your question in a quick glance. Too much question mark, not sure what are you asking for, and those topics are hard to answer IMO. Try to add figure to show your problem and use markdown to format your question, then we can talk about those vague topic

Comment: Also, there is only 2,000 people own 200+ reputation on this website. And maybe half of them ask a question and gain a lot of reputation while never using this website since the first post. This forum might not be that popular compare to Blender Artists and other forum maybe.

Comment: also since this is not a question about using blender it fits better in the [meta]. Also check  [ask] to figure out how to improve your questions.

Comment: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Thanks for the feed back.

Comment: I will go through some questions and add some feedback. If you actually care about this site you will update them and make them be a good contribution.

Comment: I always sound very rude, because of my flavourless descriptive tone. Sorry about that. But ask yourself the following question. If you haven't fixed all of your previous questions yet (it's been 10 days) and improved them, how do expect other users to give their free time and not only help you, but a large number of other people on this site?

Comment: I was under the idea that this website was a simple forum. If this is anything more than that, then maybe I should look somewhere else.

Comment: This site works a bit different than most: is a questions and answers site,  it is **not a forum** or social media. At the bottom of the page in the regular site there is a link that reads "tour" click on it to understand how the site works.